# Odoo11 - Multi company website portal user dashboard

Tags: javascript, python, web, odoo, odoo-11

In **Odoo v11.0**, it doesn't provide multi company support on the website. So portal users can only access 1 company records that are set in *Current Company* at user profile.

**My problem**: is there any way to identify the root controller method or js method which calls every time on the portal when a user clicks?

**Goal**: In two different URLs, User login with their credentials and based on the root method hook can easily inject the company.

**Tried/Analysis**:

- I have overridden **_login()** method and successfully changed the company based on the website URL. When I login to a 2nd company, my previous tab shows only the last website company records. I want to allow them to access both companies at the same time.
- controllers - index() - web_client() - failed

Comment: I don't know if it's the best solution in all your context but. By defaut a global rules say "You can see only data from you current company". If you set the group 'Internal user' to this rule. The rule no longer global, and portal user of the website by default can see all information of all companies.